# Divided by zero encountered when doing minimization in python

Tags: python, error-handling, scipy

I have the follow piece of code (part of a bigger code):

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import multivariate_normal 
from scipy.optimize import minimize as scipy_min

def f_loglike(x):
    pmean = [1.54379044]
    pCov = [[0.00013136]]
    return -np.log(multivariate_normal(pmean[0],pCov).pdf(x))

scipy_min(f_loglike, 1, method='Nelder-Mead', tol=1e-6)
```

When I run it, I am getting 2 warnings: `RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in log` and `RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in subtract np.max(np.abs(fsim[0] - fsim[1:])) <= fatol):`

and the output of the function is:

```
final_simplex: (array([[1.],
   [1.]]), array([inf, inf]))
       fun: inf
   message: 'Maximum number of function evaluations has been exceeded.'
      nfev: 200
       nit: 67
    status: 1
   success: False
         x: array([1.])
```

I am not sure what is going on (or how to debug it). This should be just the minimum of a - a Gaussian (or the maximum of a Gaussian), which is trivial (the answer should be pmean). Also, in the formula for the Gaussian, given that the covariance (or the standard deviation in this case) is fixed, there is no place where I would get any division by zero, so the first warning makes no sense to me. Can someone help me understand what is going on and how to fix it? Thank you!

Comment: The documentation for minimize says that it uses a gradient function, so I suspect it is intended to be used when `f` is a "smooth" function.  You're essentially passing it a list of random numbers.

Comment: @FrankYellin what do you mean by random numbers? The function -np.log(multivariate_normal(pmean[0],pCov).pdf(x)) is smooth (it is the log of a Gaussian). If I do x = np.arange(-10,10,0.01) and plot that function vs x I get a smooth function

Comment: Sorry.  My bad.  I missed that you were calling pdf().  Ignore my comment.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the function slightly based on the [SciPy documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.multivariate_normal.html) and changed the initial condition slightly. I got something that runs, maybe because the initial condition was starting in a place that gave a zero value in the argument of `log()`. Here is what I got, but I don't know if this is what you were looking for:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import multivariate_normal 
from scipy.optimize import minimize as scipy_min

def f_loglike(x):
    pmean = [1.54379044]
    pCov = [[0.00013136]]
    return -np.log(multivariate_normal.pdf(x,pmean[0],pCov))

print(scipy_min(f_loglike, 1.5, method='Nelder-Mead', tol=1e-6))
```

It returns:

```
final_simplex: (array([[1.54379025],
       [1.54379082]]), array([-3.54984592, -3.54984592]))
           fun: -3.549845922780753
       message: 'Optimization terminated successfully.'
          nfev: 36
           nit: 18
        status: 0
       success: True
             x: array([1.54379025])
```